# Id field does not set by returned key

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, h2, transactional

First: Generated Id does not maps to entity object. From h2 logs it seems like that generatedKeys resultset is returned, and jpa gets key by resultSet.getInt(1). But object id field not set to returned value.

Second: do it necessary to use transactions? Now I am testing simple CRUD commands and do no need transactions, I want every method called in DAO to be commited. So I Set autocommit = true, but hibernate keeps setting it to false . How it can be solved? I want after method called in DAO connect with my own connection and test data with. Now I just created @AfterTransactional and check data, but it is pretty bad solution.

Model
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "personal_phone_tbl")
    public class PersonalPhone {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String number;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
  }
}
```

DAO

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonalPhoneDao {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void create(PersonalPhone phone) {
        entityManager.merge(phone);
    }
```

context.xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/phonebook" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="phonebook-persistence"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="phonebook.*"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

h2 Log

```
    INFO: Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@2267889d testClass = PersonalPhoneDaoTest, testInstance = com.getjavajob.web06.zhukm.PersonalPhoneDaoTest@3b3a0d10, testMethod = testInsert@AbstractDaoTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4b06e721 testClass = PersonalPhoneDaoTest, locations = '{classpath:dao-context.xml, classpath:dao-context-overrides.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@602fb3d0]; rollback [false]
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[6]: 
/**/conn3.close();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: disconnecting session #6
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: disconnected session #6
Hibernate: insert into personal_phone_tbl (phone) values (?)
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.prepareStatement("insert into personal_phone_tbl (phone) values (?)", 1);
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/PreparedStatement prep1 = conn1.prepareStatement("insert into personal_phone_tbl (phone) values (?)");
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/prep1.setString(1, "+7(909)6696578");
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/prep1.executeUpdate();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 exclusive write lock requesting for SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 exclusive write lock added for SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 exclusive write lock unlock SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 shared read lock unlock SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 4 shared read lock requesting for PERSONAL_PHONE_TBL
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 4 shared read lock ok PERSONAL_PHONE_TBL
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/*SQL l:49 #:1 t:2*/insert into personal_phone_tbl (phone) values (?) {1: '+7(909)6696578'};
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/ResultSet rs21 = prep1.getGeneratedKeys();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/*SQL #:1*/SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() WHERE SCOPE_IDENTITY() IS NOT NULL;
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/rs21.next();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/ResultSetMetaData rsMeta0 = rs21.getMetaData();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.getCatalog();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/rsMeta0.getColumnCount();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/rs21.getInt(1);
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/rs21.close();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/prep1.getWarnings();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/prep1.clearWarnings();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/prep1.getMaxRows();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/prep1.getQueryTimeout();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/*SQL l:58 #:1 t:1*/SELECT VALUE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME=? {1: 'QUERY_TIMEOUT'};
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/prep1.close();
-----------------------------> personalPhone.getId()0
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.commit();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 4 shared read lock unlock PERSONAL_PHONE_TBL
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/*SQL */COMMIT;
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.setAutoCommit(true);
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.commit();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/*SQL */COMMIT;
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.isClosed();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.getWarnings();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.clearWarnings();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.isClosed();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[4]: 
/**/conn1.clearWarnings();
Jan 29, 2016 2:48:50 AM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext endTransaction
INFO: Committed transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@2267889d testClass = PersonalPhoneDaoTest, testInstance = com.getjavajob.web06.zhukm.PersonalPhoneDaoTest@3b3a0d10, testMethod = testInsert@AbstractDaoTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@4b06e721 testClass = PersonalPhoneDaoTest, locations = '{classpath:dao-context.xml, classpath:dao-context-overrides.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
-----------------------------> @AfterTransaction
-----------------------------> personalPhone.getId()0
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: connecting session #7 to mem:test
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/*SQL */SET MODE MYSQL;
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/*SQL */SET DB_CLOSE_DELAY -1;
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/Connection conn4 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "SA", "");
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/conn4.setAutoCommit(false);
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/Statement stat2 = conn4.createStatement();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/ResultSet rs22 = stat2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM personal_phone_tbl");
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/*SQL #:1*/SELECT * FROM personal_phone_tbl;
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/rs22.next();
----------------------------->ResultSet
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
   /**/rs22.getObject(1);
1
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/rs22.getObject(2);
+7(909)6696578
----------------------------->ResultSet
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/stat2.close();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 jdbc[7]: 
/**/conn4.close();
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: disconnecting session #7
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: disconnected session #7
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: closing mem:test from shutdown hook
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: disconnecting session #4
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: closing mem:test
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 exclusive write lock requesting for SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 exclusive write lock added for SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 exclusive write lock unlock SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 lock: 1 shared read lock unlock SYS
2016-01-29 02:48:50 database: closed
```

Test

```
@Before
public void createDb() {
    super.dropTables();
    super.createDb();
    personalPhone = new PersonalPhone();
    personalPhone.setNumber("123456");
}

@Override
public void testInsert() {
    personalPhoneDao.create(personalPhone);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------> personalPhone.getId()"+personalPhone.getId());
    connect();
    try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SELECT);
        if(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println("----------------------------->ResultSet");
            System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(1));
            System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            System.out.println(resultSet.getObject(2));
            System.out.println("----------------------------->ResultSet");
        } else {
            Assert.fail();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE personal_phone_tbl(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
phone VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
employee_id INT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee_tbl(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

The generated Id will start at the next Id so if you have a row will 101 as an id, the next will be 102

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Will start at the first unused value. If there is nothing in the table they should do the same. Usually you should use GenerationType.AUTO that does what you expect.

Comment: Still getting get.id()=0

Comment: I think I need Identity as id generated by auto increment in a table?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I though merge(entity) modifies object that passed into it. Solution is to change create method:

```
 public PersonalPhone create(PersonalPhone phone) {
        return entityManager.merge(phone);
    }
```